# What is Activity Score in MIKROS?

Tags: mikros-analytics, mikros-game-analytics

I'm currently checking out the MIKROS documentation and have trouble understanding what the Activity Score is. I understand that people who spend more time on your games are ranked higher, but what do the associated categories mean?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Players are ranked into three categories based on the Activity Score they have.

Players with an Activity Score of 8-10 are classified as "Legendary" players. They spend a great majority of their free time playing games, and thus, are a highly sought-after type of player.

Players with an Activity Score of 5-7 are classified as "Core" players. While not as dedicated as the "Legendary" players, these players still enjoy playing games. They just prefer to play games from varying genres.

Players with an Activity Score less than 5 are classified as "Casual" players. These players don't invest significant time into a certain game, and just play whenever they feel like it.